# Error trying to add Table editor to .emacs

Tags: table

I downloaded the Table editor for emacs [table.el](http://table.sourceforge.net/). I then edited my .emacs file to load the table file as follows

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/manual")
(load "table.el")
(require 'table)
```

Opening the emacs in debug-mode throws me the following error

```
Wrong type argument: integerp, (32 . 126)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode) `table.el` is provided with emacs since version 22...

I get the same kind of error by trying the sourceforge version, but the bundled version works fine.  It is documented in emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html#Text-Based-Tables).